# HtmlEncode Local resources

Tags: asp.net, localization, html-entities

I have a web site that uses local resources. The main text (so not the labels, etc.) on de default page is stored in a file. This file is added to my local resources file default.aspx.fi-FI.resx and is named text-defaultPage. It's a regular text file with tags etc.

The problem is however, that the text is Finnish in other words it uses a lot of characters having umlaut (ä) and other special characters.
The person for whom the web site is wants to edit this text himself but he doesn't know anything about programming, html entities etc.

Is there a way to make it so that those characters are encoded with say htmlEncode?

in my Global.asax I check for the selected language and the page gets reload with that language.

## Edit

Never mind, I made the files Unicode text files.

Comment: What have you tried? Simply run it through Server.HtmlEncode and see if you get the result you are looking for.

Comment: See the big "Edit" ? Read what is beneath :)
Saved as unicode text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem is make the files unicode.